# Erro Wordpress - cURL library

Tags: php, wordpress

Chegou um site aqui na empresa para atualizarmos os posts etc, porém, toda págna que crio, eu não consigo acessa-la após a publicação.

Me é exibido esses erros:

```
Error connecting to http://www.popmundi.com.br/?p=2370 for caching (HTTP code 301). PHP "safe_mode" or "open_basedir" is defined — the PHP cURL library cannot follow URL redirects. Requests to cache this URL will be ignored for 900 second(s).

Error retrieving webpage from http://www.popmundi.com.br/?p=2370.
```

Alguma idéia do que pode ser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925213/something-went-wrong-with-curlopt-followlocation

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar atualizar os permalinks indo em: Configurações > Links permanentes > Salvar Alterações.

Além disso, tentar limpar o cache. Procure por plugins de cache e tente executa uma limpeza.